# Can Villagers use fence gates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have managed to trap most of my villagers in houses that have the back "patio" area of the house (the small fenced off area out the back of the house).

[image]

Unfortunately, now I have to break the fence every time I want to get in and trade with them. So I was wondering; can villagers use fence gates like a door to enter/leave an area?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, villagers are not able to use fence gates. I tested this in creative, and they always used a long route with a door rather than a short route with a fence gate. I even blocked off the door and they just stood there.

Answer (score 3):

**No**. Villagers can only open and close wooden doors, but they cannot open and close fence gates. You can, of course, set up a fence gate, but the villagers may try to escape through that opening when you open the fence gate. A better way to trade with villagers is to set up a booth-like thing:

```
F-Fence V=Villager



FFF  FFF
FVFFFFVF
FVVVVVVF
FFFFFFFF
```

This way, they cannot escape and you can still trade with them.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, they can't.

They cannot use any mechanism without the help of redstone or stuff like pressure plates for wooden doors.

Answer (score 1):

No. Villagers can not open gates but can open doors. I built a house and villagers kept walking in, so I decided to put a fence gate in front of the door when you walk in. Although this helped a lot I happened to get villagers in some rooms of the house from time to time.